# Laravel modal dont functioning in script in blade

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

So i have a strange problem. I have a form modal that opens when i click a button, All i want to do is reopen the modal when there are validation errors so I do this. In my blade template home.blade.php.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        @if (count($errors) > 0) {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }


    </script>
@endsection
```

When I put an alert in the script above it works fine but the modal doesnt reopen. ok and When i try opening my modal in my javascript file it works.Im confused would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your blade syntax should be as:

```
@if(count($errors) > 0)
      //your opening modal code goes here
@endif
```

It also depends on where you are loading your bootstrap JS files. If your bootstrap file is loaded after the above code then it will not load as the file is not loaded yet.

The simple option is to load your bootstrap JS files at the top of the `body` tag.

Answer (score 0):

The blade syntax that you're using is not correct (read the reference in https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#if-statements) 
And like #Amit said you got to make sure the javascript code to open your modal is loaded after the Bootstrap Js file is loaded, maybe using the $(document).ready() (refer to https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        @if (count($errors) > 0)
            //show the modal
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        @endif
    });
</script>
```